# What are some suggestions for analysis of and model development for a small sample of data?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, small-sample, multivariate-regression, path-model

I originally planned on path analysis utilizing multivariate multiple regression to test my hypothetical model - but I am not getting my sample size. I have looked at non-parametric regression techniques but - am not sure how I can develop my model using these techniques - or if a path model would even be useful at this point. I need a minimum N of 155 per my power analysis for my planned analyses - I currently have 45 and don't see much hope in increasing that number substantially within my somewhat limited timeframe ... so, Any suggestions?